# Increasing Download Speed

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel, socks

I had an interesting thought:  Would it be somewhat possible to increase download speed (and potentially upload speed) like a download accelerator does, but using a socks proxy that splits your traffic over 10 concurrent SSH tunnels?  It wouldn't have to be too sophisticated due to the nature of how this would work; you could simply have a program split the packets(?) over each tunnel with a SOCKS proxy frontend.  In theory, it should work nicely.  Is there anything out there that does this?

Comment: If your download speed is 1.0Mb/s you wont get more than 1.0Mb/s...

Comment: Why would that increase your download speed?

Comment: @dashboard While I agree with what you're saying, I'm in a situation where my ISP is cheap (or broke) and has way less bandwidth than they should.  I am able to get better speeds from servers that are perfectly capable of uploading at 10mb/s with a download accelerator, whereas usually I get 1/10th the speed I should be getting without a download accelerator.

Comment: ok so the limitation is your isp? you realize that if your isp has a 10Mbs connection for 10 people that if all 10 of you are on and your pulling 5.0Mbs down, the rest of the people will have to share 5.0Mbs...

Comment: @dashboard I understand that.

Comment: just torrent everything...

Comment: A download accelerator can not actually increase your throughput. If you can get 1Mbps max, then all the download accelerator does is give you pre-cached content faster than your ISP can fetch it on its own...

Comment: @dashboard unfortunately, that isn't an option when watching YouTube, or streaming Netflix.  This type of setup that I am proposing should work for those.

Comment: personally im not even sure where your coming from - is your isp tapped ? whats the download speed at your house? how do you expect more connections via a proxy front-end to give you more speed? thanks.

Comment: @dashboard On a normal HTTP direct download, I usually get 128kb/s average.  I pay for 1024kb/s.  With a download accelerator (a program that splits the download across about 10 connections), I can get my full capable speed.  Torrents work amazing too because they are split from multiple connections.

Comment: i see - its your isp that is limited - the max you will ever see of of your connection is 1024kb/s because your isp limits it there. in reality you'll only get 128kb/s - splitting up your connections only helps because if there are 100 people all trying to download and you are 10 of them you'll be 10/100 instead of 1/100....

Comment: @dashboard The same principle should apply to splitting my whole connection across 10 tunnels.  I should have quicker speeds that are greater than 128kb/s.

Comment: The idea behind the download accelerator is to 1). enforce use of zlib compression on traffic; 2). download different parts of the file concurrently to prevent speed loss caused by lag. It doesn't really make you download anything faster than your connection allows you to, just make you use it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

A tunnel encapsulates IP traffic inside another IP packet, which incurs additional bytes of traffic to transmit and receive.  As well, on either side of the tunnel, traffic will incur delays as it's wrapped and unwrapped.  Oh, and since traffic through a tunnel has a smaller MTU, additional overhead is incurred here as well.  So, I cannot think of a situation where this would provide an speed advantage.